# Continuously load a file in an html page without prompt

Tags: javascript, html

I am a complete beginner in HTML/Javascript and I want to make a page that will run locally (using the python webserver and published online with ngrok) and will be loading a csv file that is being refreshed every few seconds. The csv file is placed in the same folder as my html file.

I have managed to make an html page with a button to load the file. When I click the button, I get a prompt to select the csv file, anywhere on my disk. Once selected, the page refreshes by itself every half a second.

Monitoring.htm

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Daily Monitoring</title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<input type="file" id="MonitoringField" value="Select File" onchange="loadFile()"></input>
<br/>
<div id="data"></div>

<script src="FileReader.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

FileReader.js

```js
setInterval(function loadFile(){
    var file = document.getElementById("MonitoringField");
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function(e)
        {
            var getCSVData = e.target.result;
            var rows = getCSVData.split("\n");
            var html = '<table border="1">';
            html += "<col width='120'><col width='80'><col width='80'><col width='80'><col width='80'><col width='80'><col width='80'><col width='80'><col width='80'>"
            rows.forEach((data, index) => {
                html += "<tr>";
                var value = data.split(",");
                html += "<td>" + value[0] + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + value[1] + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + value[2] + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + value[3] + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + value[4] + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + value[5] + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + value[6] + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + value[7] + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + value[8] + "</td>";
                html += "</tr>";
            });
            html += '</table>';
            document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = html;
            document.getElementById("data").style.color="blue";
        };
    fr.readAsText(file.files[0]);
}, 500);
```

The problem is that when I launch the page, I need to click on the button to load the file. Is there a way to automate the process by hardcoding the name of the file that is located within the same directory in such a way that when I launch the html page, the file is loaded automatically?

Also, the js file is assumes that the csv file has 9 columns, which is correct because the csv file is formatted like this. Is there a better way of coding this without knowing the number of columns in advance?

Comment: This sounds like an xy problem.  What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?  A solution that involves refreshing the page every half second doesn't sound like a good user experience.

Comment: @praneybehl is correct. I have a file that refreshes every N seconds (many values change at once, not just a few). I want to display this on an html page but I don't want to have to select the file by clicking a button. Is there a way to specify that the file is 'filename.csv' without having to manually choose the file?

Comment: It appears that you are want to listen to file changes and update the content of the HTML you are rendering on the page. The code above is client side/browser code. The browser doesn’t allow access to the file system. What you need to do is write server side code using either python or node.js(Javascript) to get access to the file system, and then listen to file changes and refresh the code. If you are a beginner, there maybe a bit involved in it. 

Pointers: Search for node fs for file-system, chokidar for listening file change events, express to serve the HTML page.